# JMeter as HTTP Server

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to use Jmeter for a test where it can work as both HTTP server and client?

To be specific, can it answer to GET request received with 200 Ok (+ Payload) and also send POST messages (+Payload) at a specific rate?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for the [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server)

Otherwise if you want to test your workload distribution or throughput you can consider using [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) instead of HTTP Request samplers.

For the "specific rate" - see [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

Comment: HTTP Mirror Server will actually send the same request it receives (if I'm not wrong). I need something which can actually respond to GET requests with 200 Ok (with payload). Is it possible in JMeter?

Comment: Not out of the box, you can consider using i.e. [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) server, it can be either used in standalone mode (as a separate application) or integrated with JMeter, for example put into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and started/stopped/configured using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wiremock actually solved my problem. I'm running it Standalone as of now, will try and integrate it with JMeter later.